# Why doesn't "where" work as I would expect here to select certain results?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm running the following PowerShell and my questions is why doesn't the second command return any results?  Also, should I be using `where` or `Where-Object`?  See screenshot below.

```
Write-Host "This displays all..." -ForegroundColor Green
Get-Command -Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell"

Write-Host "This displays nothing..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Get-Command -Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell" | Where-Object ($_.Name -like '*Tfs*')
```

[image]

Comment: You need curly braces: e.g. `Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Tfs*'}`

Comment: D'OH! Make your comment an answer and I'll mark it. I've tried using this method several times and just pushed off figuring out the real issue for a while now. Why `where-object` over `where`?

Comment: @AlexKwitny Because that's the real name. `where` is just an alias for `Where-Object` - no functional difference

Comment: Ah that makes me feel better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Where-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) requires either a scriptblock or a comparison statement (3.0+).

In your case, replacing the parenthesis with a curly brace would work:

```
Get-Command -Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell" |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like '*Tfs*'}
```

Or you could use a comparison statement:

```
Get-Command -Module "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell" |
    Where-Object -Property Name -like '*Tfs*'
```